# Unable to use r package: esquisse

Tags: r, r-package

I am trying the use the R package esquisse . I have no issues while trying to install it . But when I try to use it I get the following error :

```
Error in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...) : 
  unable to load shared object '/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so':
  dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so, 6): Library not loaded: /opt/X11/lib/libcairo.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/gdtools/libs/gdtools.so
  Reason: image not found
```

This is a new machine I am trying to get this installed on.

Comment: So I did a clean install for `gdtools` and `esquisse`. But as soon I call the library `esquisse` I get this error `Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘esquisse’ in dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...):
`

Comment: So I installed quartz and rebooted the machine and it works now.